# Are the elements of a module also called vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, terminology

Are the elements of a module also called vectors? Or if someone says 'vector', are they talking only about a vector space? If no context is given, are there some standard assumptions?

Comment: I think if absolutely no context is given then you're out of luck and cannot safely make assumptions.  It seems unlikely though for there to be absolutely no context.  If it is from a book, then authors usually give definitions or describe their conventions to avoid ambiguity.  If it is from a paper and unclear, maybe that field has particular conventions.

Comment: As a data point, I don't think I've ever read anyone use the word *vector* to refer to an element of a module **except** when the module is $R^n$, so that one says «column vector» or «row vector» without any qualms.

Comment: I call them vectors, in full generality! (Sometimes.) Typically this kind of terminology isn't needed when you just work with modules, but once you start working with tensor products, you often want to stress that something is a vector in a tensor factor as opposed to in the whole tensor product.

Comment: Vector spaces are free modules over a field. So in a [free module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module), yes it is natural to think to the elements as vectors of $R^n$. If the module is not free, then no (see how [any abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Examples))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call this an answer, it is just my opinion.

The elements of a given vector space I would only call vectors, if the vector space is $k^n$.(Probably I am missing something...) Why? For example I would not call matrices, polynomials or functions whose codomain is a vector space vectors.

On the other hand given a generic vector space I would call the elements vectors. For instance I *apply a norm to vector.*

I am tempted to say I call vectors $v \in V$ a vector if $V= \bigoplus k$. Now there is alway an isomorphism so for me it is legit to call elements of a generic vector space vectors, but given a specific vector space it should be "canonically" $\bigoplus k$.

Now if I transfer this to modules over a ring $R$, I think it is fine to call elements of modules of the form $\bigoplus R$ vectors, but in general I would not call the elements of a module vector.

Comment: This is a very good point (about not calling matrices, polynomials, functions whose codomain is a vector space vectors). I think some people call "vector spaces" "linear spaces" instead for this very reason.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**  Normally we do not have special names like this ...

Elements of a group are called *groupies*

Elements of a ring are called *ringlets*

Comment: Are you serious? wtf

Comment: The first line ie serious.